# Inserting array field from scala using Jooq

Tags: postgresql, scala, jooq

I'm using Postgres and Jooq

```scala
object JooqBuilder {
  private val defaultSettings = new Settings()
    .withRenderFormatted(true)
    .withRenderNameStyle(RenderNameStyle.AS_IS)
    .withParseDialect(SQLDialect.POSTGRES)


  def default(conn: Connection) =
    DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.POSTGRES, defaultSettings)
}
```

Here is my insert

```scala
        val insert = JooqBuilder
          .default(conn)
          .insertInto(
            table(MY_TABLE),
            field("id", classOf[String]),
            field("dimensions", classOf[Array[String]]),            
            field("dimensionCodes", classOf[Array[Long]])
          )

        items.foreach { i =>
          insert.values(
            i.id,            
            i.dimensions.toArray,     // scala List[String] to java array     
            i.dimensionCodes.toArray  // scala List[Long] to java array        
          )
        }
        insert.execute()
```

It fails in runtime with

```
Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException: class [J cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Object; ([J is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
  at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.from(Convert.java:520)
  at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert0(Convert.java:324)
  at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:316)
  at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:387)
  at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.convert(DefaultDataType.java:825)
  at org.jooq.impl.InsertImpl.addValue(InsertImpl.java:334)
  at org.jooq.impl.InsertImpl.values(InsertImpl.java:314)
  at org.jooq.impl.InsertImpl.values(InsertImpl.java:273)
  at org.jooq.impl.InsertImpl.values(InsertImpl.java:124)
```

i suspect that `i.dimensionCodes.toArray` returns array of primitives
I've checked debugger

```java
else if (fromClass.isArray()) {
    Object[] fromArray = (Object[]) from;

    // [#3062] [#5796] Default collections if no specific collection type was requested
```

`from` is long[]

is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Why aren't you using jOOQ's code generator?

Comment: didn't find an easy way to make it work with scala play framework, migrations, scala 2.12...

Comment: I really recommend you try again, you're missing out on many features, see https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation. I'm aware that wasn't your main question here, but many problems similar to this one arise because of not using generated code.

Comment: anyway thanks for your help, another reason is "promised an exception. You can’t use the code generator when your schema is dynamic" 
my key thing is dynamic tables with various schemas...

Comment: OK, tough luck then :)

Answer (score 1):

```scala
t.dimensionCodes.toArray.map(l => java.lang.Long.valueOf(l))
```

explicit boxing helped.